# pylint flagging assignment-from-no-return when instantiating a coroutine generator

Tags: python, pylint

I am getting a `pylint` error I don't understand. I defined a generator (which I am using as a coroutine), and where I instantiate the generator, `pylint` complains, even though the assignment returns a generator and not a return value:

```
E1111: Assigning result of a function call, where the function has no return (assignment-from-no-return)
```

Minimum reducible example:

```py
def test():
    print((yield))

a = test()
print(a)
next(a)
try:
    a.send("hello, world")
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

The line `a = test()` is where the error is flagged. Since `test()` is a generator instantiation, not a function call, I don't understand the error. I tried changing `(yield)` to `(yield None)` or `(yield True)` to no avail. Adding a `return True` gives me a `no-member` error.

Execution:

```bash
$ python3 /tmp/test.py
<generator object test at 0x7f9de7801b30>
hello, world
```

Yes, I can disable it, but I prefer to fully understand it before I disable it.

If I convert it to a traditional generator, it does not complain:

```py
def test():
    yield True

a = test()
print(a)
next(a)
```

Comment: Afaik, the expression is required. You can't just `yield`, you need to `yield None`, `yield True`, `yield something`, etc. See [Yield expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr).

Comment: I tried both of those, as I stated, and the problem remained. The code runs great, it just doesn't pass `pylint`.

Comment: What's `send`? It doesn't normally exist on a generator so I'd expect an error and `no-member` sounds like the right kind of error for that.

Comment: @Ouroborus See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator%20send#generator.send

Comment: Splitting `print((yield True))` across two lines, `b = (yield True)` and `print(b)`, makes E1111 go away for me. I wonder if pylint doesn't like the anonymous value being passed directly from `yield` to `print`.